# GAE send_mail not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This script is not working,

```
class EmailPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            mail.send_mail(
                self.request.get("email"), "receiver@example.com",
                self.request.get("subject"), self.request.get("body")
            )
        except: 
            self.response.out.write("Not working")
```

It responds with "Not working", but if I switch the sender and receiver it works fine. I want the email provided by the user to be the sender and "receiver@example.com" to receive the email.

Comment: What's the exception? You should catch it and print its stack trace so that you know more.

Comment: @tayfun How do I go about printing it's stack trace?

Comment: @cinderblock: get rid of the whole try/except block. Catching exceptions you can't handle and writing your own useless error message is a bad idea. (Assuming you don't have debugging turned on, the error will go to your logs, not the browser)

Comment: @tayfun The log says "Unauthorized sender Traceback". I think it's only allowing the admin to send emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the sender address as you like. See [google's appengine docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail) for this:

> The sender address
>   must be one of the following types:
>
> The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can
>   add administrators to an application using the Administration Console.
>   The address of the user for the current request signed in with a
>   Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address
>   with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be
>   on a domain managed by Google Apps. Any valid email receiving address
>   for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com). Any valid email
>   receiving address of a domain account, such as support@example.com.
>   Domain accounts are accounts outside of the Google domain with email
>   addresses that do not end in @gmail.com or @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.